# How do I make this URL ending in a period work in the comments?

Tags: support, bug, comments, hyperlinks, url-encoding

With this URL:

https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Grants:IdeaLab/Transform_LaTex_formulas_in_spoken_words_and_make_it_readable_with_text_to_speech_programs.

It is broken unless I add a `\` to the end in front of a period:
https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Grants:IdeaLab/Transform_LaTex_formulas_in_spoken_words_and_make_it_readable_with_text_to_speech_programs.

And it works. However in the comments, I can't get this to work: (See the comments)

Comment: https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Grants:IdeaLab/Transform_LaTex_formulas_in_spoken_words_and_make_it_readable_with_text_to_speech_programs\.
https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Grants:IdeaLab/Transform_LaTex_formulas_in_spoken_words_and_make_it_readable_with_text_to_speech_programs.

Neither work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the markdown for links:

```
[https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Grants:IdeaLab/Transform_LaTex_formulas_in_spoken_words_and_make_it_readable_with_text_to_speech_programs.](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Grants:IdeaLab/Transform_LaTex_formulas_in_spoken_words_and_make_it_readable_with_text_to_speech_programs.)
```

Comment: [https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Grants:IdeaLab/Transform_LaTex_formulas_in_spoken_words_and_make_it_readable_with_text_to_speech_programs.](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Grants:IdeaLab/Transform_LaTex_formulas_in_spoken_words_and_make_it_readable_with_text_to_speech_programs.)