# Is dropping the final period in a bare url done by-design?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I have no idea if this is a potentially exploitable security issue or just a nit pick. In [this comment](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16478/what-are-these-gizmos-at-mauna-loa-observatory/16479?noredirect=1#comment34683_16479):

> yep! ;-) btw that's [A._B._and_C.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._B._and_C.) If you just past the link without the brackets, the SE url parser (for lack of a better name) thinks you made a mistake and truncates the link before the final period: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._B._and_C.

I point out that a bare url (from Wikipedia) that ends in a period is truncated, and sends you to the url without the period.

This automatic behavior produces a bad link when a good (but bare) link is pasted.

Is there any way to avoid this? I don't think it rises to the level of a bug, but is the auto-dropping of the trailing period in the url done [by-design](/questions/tagged/by-design)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer the question in the title: **yes**. When URLs are auto-linked trailing periods, commas, question marks, etc. are discarded. This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) for obvious reasons (i.e. ending of sentences often contain an URL) as explained by [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha) in [Why isn't the period rendered after a question link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180001/437611).

The way to avoid it is to use the Markdown formatting for URLs as explained in [How do I make this URL ending in a period work in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287167/437611). That is, use `[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._B._and_C.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._B._and_C.)` or `[<short-description>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._B._and_C.)`.